# What is the basis of this algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a complex field and let  the factor $A=\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, where $(x^2)$ is the ideal that generated by $x^2$.

What is the basis of this algebra?

I think that this algebra has two basis and I think the set will be like below

$\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)=\{a+bx|a,b\in \mathbb{C}\}$

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the set $\{1, x\}$ is a basis of the $\mathbb C$-vector space $A=\frac{\mathbb C[x]}{(x^2)}$:

- They obviously generate $A$, because if $\overline{p(x)}\in A$, we can write it as $p(x)=q(x)\cdot x^2+r(x)$ with $r(x)=ax+b$, so $\overline{p(x)}=\overline{ax+b}$.
- They are linearly independent because if $\overline{ax+b}=\overline 0$, then $ax+b\in (x^2)$, which clearly cannot happen, because $deg(ax+b)=1<2=deg(x^2)$.